# Windows 8: Can I create a spanned volume for the system drive at installation?

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I would like to increase the Windows 8 system disk space using a spanned volume. It seems I can't create a spanned volume for the system drive after I have installed the system.

Can I create a spanned volume for the system drive during the installation of Windows 8?

Comment: FYI spanned volumes are not RAID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the install phase of windows.

What you need to consider is potentially using RAID (0, 5, 0+1 or similar) to create a larger "span" of disks and then create a larger logical drive to install your operating system onto.

Hope this helps,

Ben

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. This method requires RAID drivers. Correct?